# Middleman: How can I get the current article title?

Tags: ruby, middleman

When generating a simple blog in Middleman using the "middleman-blog" extension I get a the layout file which simply yields the content of the post.

What I want is to get the title of the current post and display that.

What I have right now:

```
<% blog.articles.each do |article| %>
    <%= link_to article.title, article %>
<% end %>
```

This loops through every post title even though only the single post content is displayed. So it outputs something like this for the url /post-title-one

---

### Post Title One Post Title Two Post Title Three

"only the content of post title one"

---

I want to try something like

```
<% blog.articles.each do |article| %>
    <%= link_to current_article.title, article %>
<% end %>
```

But it just randomly spits out two page titles.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, if you want to print the current article's title just use <%= current_article.title %>

Comment: Yeah that's basically what I was after. I did:      <a href="<%= current_article.url %>"><%= current_article.title %></a> to make it a link. If you want the answer you can post below and I'll give it you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to print the current article's title just use `<%= current_article.title %>`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking. The first block of code you gave is intended to iterate through each article in the blog and generate a link where the link text is the article's title and the target is the article. I would assume that you want to simply link to the current article, since you're on its content page.

```
<%= link_to current_article.title, current_article %>
```

That should get the job done.